# Javascript/HTML - Hide DIV until button click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide the div "status" until the button is clicked. How can I achieve this from within my js?

```js
function start(al) {
  var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.innerHTML = al + "%";
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
  var sim = setTimeout("start(" + al + ")", 1);
  if (al == 5500) {
    status.innerHTML = "100%";
    bar.value = 5500;
    clearTimeout(sim);
    var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
    finalMessage.innerHTML = "Process is complete";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="status">
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="5500" style="width:100%;"></progress>
  <span id="status"></span>
  <br>
  <center>Generating event...</center>
</div>

<center><button style="margin-top: 20px;" class="btn btn-success" onclick='start(0)'>Submit</button></center>
```

Comment: put default style as - `display : none` and then inside start change it as `display : block`

Comment: Please check my answer for a lot of *don't do this do that* information. All the advice is based on common best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use CSS, to default `visibility` to `hidden`. Then, use JS to make the div visible.

```js
function start(al) {
  var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.innerHTML = al + "%";
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
  var sim = setTimeout("start(" + al + ")", 1);
  if (al == 5500) {
    status.innerHTML = "100%";
    bar.value = 5500;
    clearTimeout(sim);
    var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
    finalMessage.innerHTML = "Process is complete";
  }
}

let btn = document.querySelector(".btn")

btn.addEventListener("click", function show(e) {
  start(0); document.querySelector(".status").style.visibility = "visible";
  btn.removeEventListener("click", show);
}, {once:true});
```

```css
.status {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="status">
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="5500" style="width:100%;"></progress>
  <span id="status"></span>
  <br>
  <center>Generating event...</center>
</div>

<center id="finalMessage"><button style="margin-top: 20px;" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button></center>
```

Comment: I have fixed a bug as well, where progress used to start again, on clicking the button again. :)

Answer (score 3):

1. **Hide** your `status` class initially.

```
.status {
   display: none;
}
```

2. When the button is pressed, using JavaScript, **un-hide** the `status` class

```
document.querySelector(".status").style.display = "block";
```

Some improvements in your code:

1. Try to avoid having the same name for the `class` and the `id`.

In your code, `status` is both **class** and **id**.

I have changed it to `status-of-progress-bar` in the below code.

2. `finalMessage` was not used as ID in your HTML, so added to `<center>` tag

> NOTE: [**center**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tag is now not recommended, and many browsers may not support it in the future.

3. Using `.disabled` property, we can disable the button when user has pressed it once, so that user cannot press the button again.

```js
function start(al) {
  document.querySelector(".btn").disabled = true;
  document.querySelector(".status").style.display = "block";
  var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  var status = document.getElementById('status-of-progress-bar');
  status.innerHTML = al + "%";
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
  var sim = setTimeout("start(" + al + ")", 1);
  if (al == 5500) {
    status.innerHTML = "100%";
    bar.value = 5500;
    clearTimeout(sim);
    var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
    finalMessage.innerHTML = "Process is complete";
  }
}
```

```css
.status {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="status">
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="5500" style="width:100%;"></progress>
  <span id="status-of-progress-bar"></span>
  <br>
  <center id="finalMessage">Generating event...</center>
</div>

<center><button style="margin-top: 20px;" class="btn btn-success" onclick='start(0)'>Submit</button></center>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, much appreciated

Comment: There is no need to work with inline styles for the task. The DOM API has the `hidden` attribute/property exactly for this.

Comment: @Luke To There's a bug in the code. if you press the `submit` button again, the progress bar bugs out.

Comment: @TechySharnav Thanks for pointing out the bug, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to work with inline styles or create your own CSS classes for the task. Any HTML element has a [`hidden` property and attribute available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) (which sync), and every browser has user agent default styles like this:

```
[hidden] { display: none; }
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('button.btn.btn-success')
    .addEventListener('click', () => start(0));
})

function start(al) {
  document.querySelector('div.status').hidden = false;
  const bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  const status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.textContent = al + "%";
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
  const sim = setTimeout(() => start(al), 1);
  if (al == 5500) {
    status.textContent = "100%";
    bar.value = 5500;
    clearTimeout(sim);
    document.getElementById('finalMessage').textContent = "Process is complete";
  }
}
```

```css
.btn.btn-success {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  width: fit-content;
}

#progressBar {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="status" hidden>
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="5500"></progress>
  <span id="status"></span>
  <br>
  <center>Generating event...</center>
  <div id="finalMessage"></div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

There is several other improvements that I made:

- You shouldn't use `innerHTML` to set text content. Use `textContent` instead.
- Use `const` and `let` instead of `var`.
- Don't use `setTimeout` with a `string` as first parameter. Instead, pass a function that makes the call you want.
- Don't use inline styles. Instead, use CSS selectors and external CSS to style your elements.
- Don't use presentational, deprecated tags like `center`. Let CSS do the visual stuff.
- Don't use inline event listeners. Instead, wait until the DOM is ready (`DOMContentLoaded` event occurs), then use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to register event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

Add line in javascript function

```js
function start() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("status")[0].style.display = "block"
......
}
```

add style in html

```html
<div class="status" style = "display:none ">

.....
```